# Typescript Ionic 2 com angularjs. Credenciais em Http post para pegar token

Tags: angularjs, http, typescript, ionic2, token

First of all good afternoon to everyone, i hope you are ok.

Im new to AngularJS. Im using Visual Studio, Ionic 2 and typescript.

I've managed to feed my app with a REST api in .net, and now i've implemented a token for testing. It is Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth ...
Before I had made the token in Xamarin and it worked. Now I try by Angularjs the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { URLSearchParams } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


public GetValidatedToken(){
  this.urlToken = 'http://localhost:63634/token';
  this.headers = new Headers();
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   // this.data = 'grant_type=password&username=' + 'User' + '&password=' + 'user1234-';    
   // this.data = "grant_type=password" + "&username=User" + "&password=user1234-";

   this.urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

   this.urlSearchParams.append('grant_type', 'password');
   this.urlSearchParams.append('username', 'User');
   this.urlSearchParams.append('password', 'user1234-');

   this.data = this.urlSearchParams.toString();


   this.http.post('http://localhost:63634/token', this.data, { headers: this.headers })
     .subscribe(res => {
        if (res.json().success) {
           window.localStorage.setItem('token', res.json());
           this.jsonresult = window.localStorage.getItem('token');                
           console.log('Sucesso!');
        } else {
           this.jsonresult = 'Erro ao pegar token.';                
           console.log('Deu erro!');
        }
  });

  return (this.jsonresult);
}
```

I want to return the token string with this function.
The mistake is that it does not succeed and it goes into the "else". Another question is the "result" of the function.
Even though I have put a message in the variable, in the other class does not return the content ... it returns "undefined"

In the other class I put it like this:

```
import { TokenValidate } from '../token/TokenValidate';

...
constructor(public http: Http, public tokenValid: TokenValidate, ) {
  this.http = http;
  this.token = this.tokenValid.GetValidatedToken();
  console.log('Token bearer :' + this.token);
}
```

I did a lot of research so I did not have to open a question, but it did not work.

Remember people that I am totally new to this, it must certainly be a ridiculous detail

The token type is "Bearer".

Thanks in advance for any help.
Att, Amanda Marins.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please only post questions in English, otherwise most of the users won't be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you @sebaferreras and Sonicd300 for the hint and the help!!  =)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve:

---

### TokenValidate class

```
>constructor(public http: Http) {
>  this.http = http;
>}
>
>public GetValidatedToken (credentials: string){
>    this.urlToken = 'http://localhost:63634/Token';
>   
>
>    var header = new Headers();
>    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
>            
>    this.http.post(this.urlToken, credentials,{ headers: header })
>      .subscribe(res => {
>      this.result = res.json();
>    localStorage.setItem('token',this.resultado.access_token);            
>    });
>
>    this.jsonresult = localStorage.getItem('token');
>    //console.log(this.jsonresult);
>
>    return
>        ( this.jsonresult );
>}
```

---

### UserService class

```
>constructor(public http: Http, public tokenValid: TokenValidate){
>    this.http = http;
>    this.headers = new Headers ({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>      'Accept': 'q = 0.8; application/json; q = 0.9'});
>    this.creds = "grant_type=password" + "&username=User" 
>        +"&password=user1234-";
>    this.token = this.tokenValid.GetValidatedToken (this.creds);
>    console.log ('Token bearer:' + this.token);
>    this.headers.append ('Authorization', 'Bearer' + this.token);
>            
>    this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
>}
>
>getUsers(){
>    if (this.data){
>       return Promise.resolve(this.data);
>    }
>       
>    return new Promise(resolve => {
>        this.http.get (this.apiUrl+'/user', this.options)
>         .map(res => res.json())
>         .subscribe(data => {
>             this.data = data;
>             solve(this.data);
>         });
>    });
>}
```

---

I hope it helps those who need it.

Thanks!! =)

Att Amanda Marins.